# Tkinter Radiobuttons autoselect and always on...Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI for one of my school projects and I have an issue with the radio buttons... When I run the script the radio buttons automatically activate and the stay on.

```
from Tkinter import *

def sel():
    label.config(text = "You have selected 'HOSTS'")
    target = "hosts"

def selnet():
    label.config(text = "You have selected 'NETWORKS'")
    target = "networks"

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var2 = IntVar()

R1 = Radiobutton(root, text = "HOSTS", var = 'hosts', value = 1, command = sel)
R1.pack(anchor = W)

R2 = Radiobutton(root, text = "NETWORKS", var = 'networks', value = 2, command = selnet)
R2.pack(anchor = W)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an option 'variable' to link two radiobuttons. E.g. (look at the end of RadioButton constructors):

```
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text = "HOSTS", var = 'hosts', value = 1, command = sel, variable=var2)
R1.pack(anchor = W)

R2 = Radiobutton(root, text = "NETWORKS", var = 'networks', value = 2, command = selnet, variable=var2)
R2.pack(anchor = W)
```